# I can't send push notification to test flight expo standalone app

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, xcode8, expo

My Application needs a feature that receives remote notification from our server. It’s work fine on expo and simulation, but on standalone iOS, it shows me the error like this

[image]

I install this app via a test flight where the ‘NOTIFICATION’ permission is return status as ‘undetermined’, so I tried to getDeviceToken and it returned the error like the image above.

when I submit app to test flight apple send the warning mail to me

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature’s entitlements do not include the “aps-environment” entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the “aps-environment” entitlement. Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor’s Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

it seems to be the push notification on capabilities section is not enable ( normally in native project I set it up in Xcode), how can I enable it on expo?

Answer (score 1):

**I already resolved this problem by rebuilding the standalone application and let the expo handle my cert for push and provision.**